# Characterization of square-summable sequences

Tags: convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm curios whether or not the following implication is true: If $x_{n} \notin \ell^2{(\mathbb{N})}$, is there necessarily a sequence $y_{n} \in \ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $x_{n}y_{n} \notin \ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily true.

Consider $x_n = 1/\sqrt n \not\in \ell_2$. Then for any $y_n \in \ell_2$

$$\| x_ny_n \|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_ny_n|^2} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |y_n|^2} = \| y_n \|_2 $$

That is, $x_ny_n \in \ell_2$ for all $y_n \in \ell_2$.